# Electron NPM application cannot find file:///eel.js, but python can

Tags: javascript, npm, electron, electron-builder, eel

I'm building a desktop application using Python, JS, HTML and CSS. I'm connecting python using eel. When I launch my desktop application through the python terminal, it works perfectly.

However, when I launch the app through electron via command line:

`$npm start`

The desktop application loads up, but it doesn't execute on any of the python backend, explained well by this error in the inspector:

`Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND eel.js:1`

I'm not sure what is causing it, I have spent the last 8 hours testing things but to no avail.

I know you may need more information but I've been checking everything, from file structure i.e. the __.py outside web folder, to inserting `<script type="text/javascript" src="/eel.js"></script>`, so please comment below what specifically you require as including every possible cause would be a very huge question. I will include whatever is relevant in edits in this question alongside the final answer for anyone with similar issues in the future.

Comment: Is the URL you're using `file:///eel.js` as shown in the title or just `/eel.js` as shown in the question itself? The latter sounds more likely to be correct (at least from the eel examples I've seen).

Comment: I'm using /eel.js in the file. "file:///eel.js" is what appears in the inspector once the app is launched.

Comment: Try relative addressing, like `eeldir/eel.js`, check the file permissions, check the letters case

Comment: It finds the file but then calls a bunch of errors, I've replaced the eel.js file with variations online and the original, problems include the following:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined (eel.js:70)
    at Object._mock_py_functions (eel.js:70)
    at Object._init (eel.js:129)
    at eel.js:173

Comment: @V.Volkov please note though that it works perfectly fine when launching through python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to run from npm. eel.js is just virtual javascript, dont bother with it.
Put this in your your_main.py file

```
import eel.browsers
```

asign your electron browser

```
eel.browsers.set_path('electron', 'node_modules/electron/dist/electron')
```

and then use it

```
eel.start('main.html', mode='electron')
```

to run, call from python:

```
python your_main.py
```

Comment: Hi I‘m doing same things now. And I have question if we distribute this electron app then how to include python the app?